# tpc-ds does not load data to table (it generates data but stuck in the loadinf step, just load table 17 out of 24 and after does nothing)

Tags: hadoop, hive, benchmarking, sandbox, analytics-for-apache-hdp

i am working in the hive benchmarking https://github.com/hortonworks/hive-testbench

i have a problem in loading data to tables. in face the TPC-ds data generator generates the data and then tryes to load them in tables but in table 17 out of 24 stops working and does nothing! i have tried several times and i gave so many time to it to be completed but it looks like it has stuck in this step, and nothing happens. plaese guide me what should i do for that?

and i cant run my queries because of missing some tables.

i am using azure with 8 core 28G ram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x24d8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this step several time and after checking the tables I understood the tables are populated with sample data but because of a problem in shell the process stops in number 17 . just takes 30 minute after the 17th job and all tables will populate.but the shell will be still freeze.